# System UI has stopped

Tags: android

So i was running my app normally , without any errors or anything , but then , both in my emulator and real device , on the last `activity` when I click to select open applications , the app just sends "**System UI has stopped** " in a loop. Can anyone help me ?

I have searched so much in the internet , and here in stack overflow , but there is only answers for this problem in AVD , but this problem keeps happening both in my real device and in all my AVDs.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I just found out that this doesn't happen only when im on last activity but in all activity the only constant is that it happens when I click the button to select all opened apps.

Comment: Did you changed your app icon?

Comment: Yes , is that about it ?

Comment: can you provide logcat and code of that activity?

Comment: Sure but this error doesn't happen in logcat.

Comment: Thank you R.R.M I changed the round icon and it worked, if you want to answer it instead of a comment I can thik , your answer right thanks for the help bro !

Comment: Yes. I have added it as an answer. Please make it right if it helped you so that others can know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the app icon of your app. It may cause this. It generally caused due to large size of app icon. Reduce your app icon size or change it.

Comment: In Android 8 and above remove launcher icons with **anydpi-v26** .